# Parsing 10-year federal note yield from the website

Tags: html, r, quantmod

Typically, this is the commonly advised way in R to download the 10-year federal note yield

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("DGS10",src='FRED')
Fed<-last(DGS10)
```

The problem is that the value retrieved is one day older than what is available on the treasury website
https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield

Is there a way to parse the above webpage to retrieve the most recent 10 yr treasury note yield?

Comment: Have you checked [`rvest`](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rvest` is a good option, as these are rendered tables. Another is:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

year = 2016
URL = paste0("https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldYear&year=",year)

urldata <- httr::GET(URL)
data <- XML::readHTMLTable(rawToChar(urldata$content),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Finds html based list element w/daily data for the year
namesCheck <- c("Date","1 mo","3 mo","6 mo","1 yr","2 yr","3 yr","5 yr","7 yr","10 yr","20 yr","30 yr")
dataCheck <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(data)){
      dataCheck[[i]] <- names(data[[i]])
}

## Returns appropriate frame
dataCheck <- which(unlist(lapply(1:length(dataCheck), function(i) 
   (dataCheck[[i]] == namesCheck)[1])) == TRUE)

data <- as.data.frame((data[dataCheck]))
names(data) <- gsub("NULL.","", names(data)) # Take out "NULL."

tail(data)

#         Date 1.mo 3.mo 6.mo 1.yr 2.yr 3.yr 5.yr 7.yr 10.yr 20.yr 30.yr
# 245 12/22/16 0.42 0.51 0.65 0.87 1.22 1.54 2.04 2.36  2.55  2.86  3.12
# 246 12/23/16 0.42 0.52 0.65 0.87 1.22 1.54 2.04 2.35  2.55  2.86  3.12
# 247 12/27/16 0.50 0.51 0.66 0.89 1.28 1.58 2.07 2.37  2.57  2.88  3.14
# 248 12/28/16 0.48 0.53 0.62 0.90 1.26 1.55 2.02 2.32  2.51  2.83  3.09
# 249 12/29/16 0.39 0.47 0.62 0.85 1.22 1.49 1.96 2.30  2.49  2.82  3.08
# 250 12/30/16 0.44 0.51 0.62 0.85 1.20 1.47 1.93 2.25  2.45  2.79  3.06
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried to pull the data using the above code of yours and it no longer works. Almost like nothing is getting loaded. Do you mind trying if it still works for you?

Comment: @Oposum Sorry it took so long to get back to you. Above is the modified code to get daily data across all years.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, Quandl.com usually offers updates earlier than FRED for Treasury yields. Data is easily imported into R via the Quandl package.

Comment: As of today, looks like Quandl is lagging the Treasury site by one day. See above modification to get updated and current data.