# Scraping federal note yield table from the treasury website

Tags: html, r, quantmod, rvest, httr

I would like to download the 10-year federal note yield from the treasury website: https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield

To parse the above webpage and retrieve the most recent 10 yr treasury note yield, I used to follow the instructions provided here:
[Parsing 10-year federal note yield from the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952589/parsing-10-year-federal-note-yield-from-the-website)

```
library(httr)
URL = "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield"

urldata <- GET(URL)
data <- readHTMLTable(rawToChar(urldata$content),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data <- as.data.frame((data[69]))
names(data) <- gsub("NULL.","", names(data)) # Take out "NULL."
```

But it no longer works.

Any thoughts what may be wrong or alternative suggestions?

Comment: I could not access the website, it says "An unexpected error has occurred". If you have the same issue you won't be able to extract the data from it.

Comment: @FernandoIrarrázavalG I can access it, and here is the direct link just in case <https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield>

Comment: Also did not work, this is what I get: https://snag.gy/tQl2ya.jpg

Comment: @FernandoIrarrázavalG not sure, I can open it in my browser without any issues

Comment: Maybe it requires some type of log in?

Comment: @FernandoIrarrázavalG no, it's a treasury website, no login, it's all public. What happens when you try just <www.treasury.gov>?

Comment: That works. 

I used a website that allows to take a screenshot of a site and it also got the error: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170416_8V_1ZM/. Maybe you have cached the webpage? Try Ctrl+Shift+F5.

Comment: @FernandoIrarrázavalG it works. if you see the sign `>`after `yield` at the the end of the link, just remove it

Comment: Why not simply download the constant maturity rates from FRED?

Comment: It's a lazy-@$$ SharePoint-based site. So, deep links are bound to break at some point as it depends on a ASCII-encoded binary "view state" object that it passes around on requests. SharePoint sites are some of the worst ones (deliberately designed by M$ to be that way) to scrape.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich FRED data is one day older than treasury website data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not answer the specific question of why your code no longer works. Here is an alternative using `rvest` package which simplifies many scraping operations. In particular below, the selection of the table is made with the class id CSS selector `.t-chart`. This makes it much more tolerant of page formatting changes. The chaining with operator %>% makes for very compact code.

```
library(rvest)
t_url = "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield"
rates <- read_html(t_url) %>%
  html_node(".t-chart") %>% 
  html_table()

rates

#       Date 1 mo 3 mo 6 mo 1 yr 2 yr 3 yr 5 yr 7 yr 10 yr 20 yr 30 yr
# 1 04/03/17 0.73 0.79 0.92 1.02 1.24 1.47 1.88 2.16  2.35  2.71  2.98
# 2 04/04/17 0.77 0.79 0.92 1.03 1.25 1.47 1.88 2.16  2.36  2.72  2.99
# 3 04/05/17 0.77 0.80 0.93 1.03 1.24 1.44 1.85 2.14  2.34  2.71  2.98
# 4 04/06/17 0.78 0.79 0.94 1.05 1.24 1.45 1.87 2.15  2.34  2.72  2.99
# 5 04/07/17 0.77 0.82 0.95 1.08 1.29 1.52 1.92 2.20  2.38  2.74  3.00
# 6 04/10/17 0.77 0.82 0.97 1.07 1.29 1.52 1.91 2.18  2.37  2.72  2.99
# 7 04/11/17 0.74 0.82 0.94 1.05 1.24 1.45 1.84 2.11  2.32  2.67  2.93
# 8 04/12/17 0.77 0.81 0.95 1.04 1.24 1.44 1.81 2.09  2.28  2.65  2.92
# 9 04/13/17 0.76 0.81 0.94 1.03 1.21 1.40 1.77 2.05  2.24  2.62  2.89
```